# Style of a specific STEP angular primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using angular with primeng and the Steps component. I'm trying to give an specific style to the elements of the steps that are disabled.

In the primeng documentation I saw this property badgeStyleClass but is not working for me, because the style of the disabled elements are not apply:

This is my code:

```
this.otherItems = [
            {
                label: 'Personal',
                command: (event: any) => { }
            },
            {
                label: 'Seat',
                disabled: true,
                command: (event: any) => { }
            },
            {
                label: 'Payment',
                command: (event: any) => { }
            },
            {
                label: 'Confirmation',
                command: (event: any) => { }
            },
            {
                label: 'Order Made',
                disabled: true,
                badgeStyleClass: '#43752b',
                command: (event: any) => { }
            }
        ];

<h3>Clickable only in an specific steps</h3>
<div class="steps">
    <p-steps [model]="otherItems" [(activeIndex)]="actIndexClickableSpecificStep" [readonly]="false"></p-steps>
</div>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by overriding the CSS of Primeng in you app. I have created an stackblitz for you. I have overridden the CSS of both, disabled and active blocks.

Here is the [Stackbliz Url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-hmua4l) for your reference.

For overrding add your own class customestepper and overridden the CSS properties like below:

```
<p-steps class="customstepper" [model]="otherItems" [(activeIndex)]="actIndexClickableSpecificStep" [readonly]="false"></p-steps>

.customstepper .ui-steps .ui-steps-item.ui-state-disabled {
  background: #ddd;
}
.customstepper .ui-steps .ui-steps-item.ui-state-disabled .ui-menuitem-link {
  color: green;
}
```

In this way, it only effect this particular stepper only and if you want to apply the same to other steppers, then just add this CSS to other steppers as well.